# Create Add Products input form like in Create new order for Magento 2 using Generic Form

Tags: magento-2.1, backend, adminform, product-grid, fieldsets

I have a custom extension that need product grid input form like in create new order like this:

[image: example]

my custom extension have database structure to connect with the product id, so if i want to edit the selected product will be shown like when editing the customer order:

```
listings
-------
entity_id
listing_name

listedproducts
---------------
entity_id
product_id
listing_id
```

I want to create this input products form using Generic Form style not UiComponent(xml), is there anyway i can achieve this?